# Springboot @DataJpaTest Integration test with external sql server db

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing, junit5

I have below repository class in my spring boot project. This repository has a method that returns Inventory data from the SQL server. This is working on my project.

```
@Repository
public interface InventoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Inventory, Integer> {
  Inventory findByInventoryIdAndCompanyId(Integer inventoryId, Integer companyId);        
}
```

I want to write a integration for the repository which should get data from dev and test environment SQL server DB.
This dev and test environment db has data already.
Below are the application.yml files in my resources folder (I have changed url and credential intentionally to show here).

**application.yml :**

```
spring:
  profiles.active: development
```

**application-developement.yml :**

```
spring:
  profiles: development

spring.datasource.type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.jdbc-url: jdbc:sqlserver://22.22.22.22:1533;instanceName=SQLSVR;databaseName=dev
spring.datasource.username: admin
spring.datasource.password: admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

**application-test.yml :**

```
spring:
  profiles: test

spring.datasource.type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.jdbc-url: jdbc:sqlserver://11.11.11.11:1533;instanceName=SQLSVR;databaseName=qa
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:sqlserver://11.11.11.11:1533;instanceName=SQLSVR;databaseName=qa
spring.datasource.username: admin
spring.datasource.password: admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Below is the test class for my repository.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ContextConfiguration
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class InventoryRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    InventoryRepository inventoryRepository;

    @Test
    public void getRepositoryByIdTest () {
        Assertions.assertEquals(1,inventoryRepository.findByInventoryIdAndCompanyId(1,1));
    }
}
```

Below is the error I am getting while performing this test

```
2021-10-18 03:35:38.917  INFO 11968 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@18d87d80 testClass = InventoryRepositoryTest, testInstance = com.cropin.mwarehouse.common.repository.InventoryRepositoryTest@437da279, testMethod = getRepositoryByIdTest@InventoryRepositoryTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@618425b5 testClass = InventoryRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.cropin.mwarehouse.CropinMWarehouseServiceApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@58695725 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@4b2bac3f, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@26794848, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@6ad82709, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@fb6c1252, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@158a8276], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@f310675]; rollback [true]
2021-10-18 03:35:38.963 DEBUG 11968 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        inventory0_.inventoryId as inventor1_10_,
        inventory0_.createdBy as createdB2_10_,
        inventory0_.createdDate as createdD3_10_,
        inventory0_.lastModifiedBy as lastModi4_10_,
        inventory0_.lastModifiedDate as lastModi5_10_,
        inventory0_.balanceWeight as balanceW6_10_,
        inventory0_.batchCreationDate as batchCre7_10_,
        inventory0_.batchNumber as batchNum8_10_,
        inventory0_.clientId as clientId9_10_,
        inventory0_.companyId as company10_10_,
        inventory0_.currencyUnitId as currenc11_10_,
        inventory0_.dateOfEntry as dateOfE12_10_,
        inventory0_.harvestReferenceId as harvest13_10_,
        inventory0_.inventoryStatus as invento14_10_,
        inventory0_.isActive as isActiv15_10_,
        inventory0_.itemId as itemId16_10_,
        inventory0_.locationId as locatio17_10_,
        inventory0_.parentInventoryId as parentI18_10_,
        inventory0_.processId as process19_10_,
        inventory0_.quantity as quantit20_10_,
        inventory0_.quantityBalance as quantit21_10_,
        inventory0_.supplierId as supplie22_10_,
        inventory0_.unitPrice as unitPri23_10_,
        inventory0_.weight as weight24_10_ 
    from
        inv.Inventory inventory0_ 
    where
        inventory0_.inventoryId=? 
        and inventory0_.companyId=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        inventory0_.inventoryId as inventor1_10_,
        inventory0_.createdBy as createdB2_10_,
        inventory0_.createdDate as createdD3_10_,
        inventory0_.lastModifiedBy as lastModi4_10_,
        inventory0_.lastModifiedDate as lastModi5_10_,
        inventory0_.balanceWeight as balanceW6_10_,
        inventory0_.batchCreationDate as batchCre7_10_,
        inventory0_.batchNumber as batchNum8_10_,
        inventory0_.clientId as clientId9_10_,
        inventory0_.companyId as company10_10_,
        inventory0_.currencyUnitId as currenc11_10_,
        inventory0_.dateOfEntry as dateOfE12_10_,
        inventory0_.harvestReferenceId as harvest13_10_,
        inventory0_.inventoryStatus as invento14_10_,
        inventory0_.isActive as isActiv15_10_,
        inventory0_.itemId as itemId16_10_,
        inventory0_.locationId as locatio17_10_,
        inventory0_.parentInventoryId as parentI18_10_,
        inventory0_.processId as process19_10_,
        inventory0_.quantity as quantit20_10_,
        inventory0_.quantityBalance as quantit21_10_,
        inventory0_.supplierId as supplie22_10_,
        inventory0_.unitPrice as unitPri23_10_,
        inventory0_.weight as weight24_10_ 
    from
        inv.Inventory inventory0_ 
    where
        inventory0_.inventoryId=? 
        and inventory0_.companyId=?
2021-10-18 03:35:39.142 DEBUG 11968 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        companymas0_.companyId as companyI1_1_0_,
        companymas0_.createdBy as createdB2_1_0_,
        companymas0_.createdDate as createdD3_1_0_,
        companymas0_.lastModifiedBy as lastModi4_1_0_,
        companymas0_.lastModifiedDate as lastModi5_1_0_,
        companymas0_.companyAddress as companyA6_1_0_,
        companymas0_.companyCode as companyC7_1_0_,
        companymas0_.companyDesc as companyD8_1_0_,
        companymas0_.companyLogo as companyL9_1_0_,
        companymas0_.companyName as company10_1_0_,
        companymas0_.companyPreferredSubDomain as company11_1_0_,
        companymas0_.contactEmail as contact12_1_0_,
        companymas0_.contactNumber as contact13_1_0_,
        companymas0_.defaultRadiusForGeoFencing as default14_1_0_,
        companymas0_.fiscalMonth as fiscalM15_1_0_,
        companymas0_.isGDPRRequired as isGDPRR16_1_0_,
        companymas0_.isActive as isActiv17_1_0_,
        companymas0_.isBlueToothRequired as isBlueT18_1_0_,
        companymas0_.isGeoFencingRequired as isGeoFe19_1_0_,
        companymas0_.isHarvestPaid as isHarve20_1_0_,
        companymas0_.isShareImage as isShare21_1_0_,
        companymas0_.isVerified as isVerif22_1_0_,
        companymas0_.isZohoEnable as isZohoE23_1_0_,
        companymas0_.planTypeId as planTyp24_1_0_,
        companymas0_.primaryCountry as primary25_1_0_,
        companymas0_.sTA as sTA26_1_0_,
        companymas0_.webSite as webSite27_1_0_ 
    from
        dbo.CompanyMaster companymas0_ 
    where
        companymas0_.companyId=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        companymas0_.companyId as companyI1_1_0_,
        companymas0_.createdBy as createdB2_1_0_,
        companymas0_.createdDate as createdD3_1_0_,
        companymas0_.lastModifiedBy as lastModi4_1_0_,
        companymas0_.lastModifiedDate as lastModi5_1_0_,
        companymas0_.companyAddress as companyA6_1_0_,
        companymas0_.companyCode as companyC7_1_0_,
        companymas0_.companyDesc as companyD8_1_0_,
        companymas0_.companyLogo as companyL9_1_0_,
        companymas0_.companyName as company10_1_0_,
        companymas0_.companyPreferredSubDomain as company11_1_0_,
        companymas0_.contactEmail as contact12_1_0_,
        companymas0_.contactNumber as contact13_1_0_,
        companymas0_.defaultRadiusForGeoFencing as default14_1_0_,
        companymas0_.fiscalMonth as fiscalM15_1_0_,
        companymas0_.isGDPRRequired as isGDPRR16_1_0_,
        companymas0_.isActive as isActiv17_1_0_,
        companymas0_.isBlueToothRequired as isBlueT18_1_0_,
        companymas0_.isGeoFencingRequired as isGeoFe19_1_0_,
        companymas0_.isHarvestPaid as isHarve20_1_0_,
        companymas0_.isShareImage as isShare21_1_0_,
        companymas0_.isVerified as isVerif22_1_0_,
        companymas0_.isZohoEnable as isZohoE23_1_0_,
        companymas0_.planTypeId as planTyp24_1_0_,
        companymas0_.primaryCountry as primary25_1_0_,
        companymas0_.sTA as sTA26_1_0_,
        companymas0_.webSite as webSite27_1_0_ 
    from
        dbo.CompanyMaster companymas0_ 
    where
        companymas0_.companyId=?
2021-10-18 03:35:39.292 DEBUG 11968 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        locationma0_.locationId as location1_22_0_,
        locationma0_.createdBy as createdB2_22_0_,
        locationma0_.createdDate as createdD3_22_0_,
        locationma0_.lastModifiedBy as lastModi4_22_0_,
        locationma0_.lastModifiedDate as lastModi5_22_0_,
        locationma0_.addressLine1 as addressL6_22_0_,
        locationma0_.addressLine2 as addressL7_22_0_,
        locationma0_.companyId as companyI8_22_0_,
        locationma0_.coordinates as coordina9_22_0_,
        locationma0_.districtId as distric10_22_0_,
        locationma0_.geoId as geoId11_22_0_,
        locationma0_.imageName as imageNa12_22_0_,
        locationma0_.isActive as isActiv13_22_0_,
        locationma0_.latitude as latitud14_22_0_,
        locationma0_.locationTypeId as locatio15_22_0_,
        locationma0_.longitude as longitu16_22_0_,
        locationma0_.name as name17_22_0_,
        locationma0_.parentLocationId as parentL18_22_0_,
        locationma0_.pincode as pincode19_22_0_,
        locationma0_.placeName as placeNa20_22_0_,
        locationma0_.stateId as stateId21_22_0_ 
    from
        inv.LocationMaster locationma0_ 
    where
        locationma0_.locationId=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        locationma0_.locationId as location1_22_0_,
        locationma0_.createdBy as createdB2_22_0_,
        locationma0_.createdDate as createdD3_22_0_,
        locationma0_.lastModifiedBy as lastModi4_22_0_,
        locationma0_.lastModifiedDate as lastModi5_22_0_,
        locationma0_.addressLine1 as addressL6_22_0_,
        locationma0_.addressLine2 as addressL7_22_0_,
        locationma0_.companyId as companyI8_22_0_,
        locationma0_.coordinates as coordina9_22_0_,
        locationma0_.districtId as distric10_22_0_,
        locationma0_.geoId as geoId11_22_0_,
        locationma0_.imageName as imageNa12_22_0_,
        locationma0_.isActive as isActiv13_22_0_,
        locationma0_.latitude as latitud14_22_0_,
        locationma0_.locationTypeId as locatio15_22_0_,
        locationma0_.longitude as longitu16_22_0_,
        locationma0_.name as name17_22_0_,
        locationma0_.parentLocationId as parentL18_22_0_,
        locationma0_.pincode as pincode19_22_0_,
        locationma0_.placeName as placeNa20_22_0_,
        locationma0_.stateId as stateId21_22_0_ 
    from
        inv.LocationMaster locationma0_ 
    where
        locationma0_.locationId=?
2021-10-18 03:35:39.663  INFO 11968 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@18d87d80 testClass = InventoryRepositoryTest, testInstance = com.cropin.mwarehouse.common.repository.InventoryRepositoryTest@437da279, testMethod = getRepositoryByIdTest@InventoryRepositoryTest, testException = org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <1> but was: <com.cropin.mwarehouse.common.entity.Inventory@5b58f639>, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@618425b5 testClass = InventoryRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.cropin.mwarehouse.CropinMWarehouseServiceApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@58695725 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@4b2bac3f, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@26794848, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@6ad82709, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@fb6c1252, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@158a8276], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :1
Actual   :com.cropin.mwarehouse.common.entity.Inventory@5b58f639
<Click to see difference>


    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:182)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:177)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:1124)
    at com.cropin.mwarehouse.common.repository.InventoryRepositoryTest.getRepositoryByIdTest(InventoryRepositoryTest.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Below are the questions for which I am looking for an answers:

1. Does @DataJpaTest only works with in memory db? Here I am trying to connect with external sql server db is it really connecting to it?
2. If @DataJpaTest is able to connect to external sql server db then why it is failing as I already have records available for above test parameter.
   3.How Can I use profiling here? There is an option as @ActiveProfile but I want to use same block of test for both the environment dev and qa, in that how this profiling will work?
   4.In error log it is showing active profile as empty, what does that mean? Is it not picking up the development profile?
3. How can I achieve integration test connecting to my dev and qa db which already has data. I don't want to use in memory db.

Please help me out with this question.

Answer (score 0):

The actual connection seems to work. `@DataJpaTest` works with any `DataSource` configuration, it just takes the opinionated approach to use an in-memory database. You already added the required code to opt-out and use your own `DataSource` with:

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
```

The actual test failure happens because you try to compare an `int` with an actual Java object. Either return all objects and check the size:

```
Assertions.assertEquals(1, inventoryRepository.findAll().size());
```

... or assert that the result is not null:

```
Assertions.assertNotNull(inventoryRepository.findByInventoryIdAndCompanyId(1,1));
```

Take a closer look at the assertion error:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :1
Actual   :com.cropin.mwarehouse.common.entity.Inventory@5b58f639
<Click to see difference>
```

FYI: You should be able to reduce the test setup to:

```
// @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) already comes with @DataJpaTest
@DataJpaTest
// @ContextConfiguration
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class InventoryRepositoryTest {
```